# How can i fix this Selenium Error: Starting Microsoft Edge WebDriver 118.0.2088.69 ) on port 39280 Only local connections are allowed

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenium-edgedriver

I already read much about the problem but i can´t solve it:

```
Starting Microsoft Edge WebDriver 118.0.2088.69 (3cedde93c7077a64704badd2b4908bc2567d26ec) on port 39280
To submit feedback, report a bug, or suggest new features, please visit https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/EdgeWebDriver

Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://aka.ms/WebDriverSecurity for suggestions on keeping Microsoft Edge WebDriver safe.
```

I´m using the MSEdge version 118.0.2088.69 and also the msedgedriver version of it. So there should be the problem i guess.

Thats´ the copy Path
`"C:\Users\A020451\OneDrive - All for One Group SE\Anlagen\Geschäfft\SeleniumWebDriver\msedgedriver.exe"`

and thats my Code just a basic

```
package seleniumbasics;

import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class EdgeBrowser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\Users\\A020451\\OneDrive - All for One Group SE\\Anlagen\\Geschäfft\\SeleniumWebDriver\\msedgedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com");

        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

What i think is, it is not going with edge business version, im on my business Laptop idk if thats making any issue

I already installed different version of msedge driver different libariese or directorys but nothing is working. Basically i just want to open a website it can be every Website. This would be a great afford

Comment: that's not an error.  It's just telling you that only local connections are allowed to the driver.  (which is good... the internet can't control your webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest version of selenium(`v4.6.0` or higher version), then you do not have to worry about manually setting the path of `msedgedriver.exe`. Selenium's built-in tool [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) will handle the downloading and managing of driver for you automatically. Basically it checks the browser version and downloads the matching driver. So you don't need the below line:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\Users\\A020451\\OneDrive - All for One Group SE\\Anlagen\\Geschäfft\\SeleniumWebDriver\\msedgedriver.exe");
```

Code can be as simple as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();  
}
```

Comment: It says i have to set the driver: 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.edge.driver system property; for more information,

I´m using selenium-java-4.15

Comment: Surely it's an old selenium version if you are seeing that Exception. Recheck the selenium version being used. Check the console error, it should display the selenium version. Share the complete error trace in the question if possible.

Comment: This is the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/failsafe/Policy
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.<clinit>(ClientConfig.java:33)
 at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:57)
 at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:49)
 at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:45)
 at seleniumbasics.EdgeBrowser.main(EdgeBrowser.java:10)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dev.failsafe.Policy
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
 ... 5 more

Comment: This is a different Exception to what you shared earlier in the first comment.

Comment: i just checked the selenium version and deleted the System.setProberty

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below snippet and let me know if this works: Selenium version: 4.14.0

```
 WebDriver driver;    
    WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
    EdgeOptions edgeOptions= new EdgeOptions();
    edgeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*", "ignore-certificate-errors");
    edgeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    edgeOptions.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[] { "enable-automation", "load-extension" });
    driver=new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com");
    driver.quit();
```